# Speech to text api for jquery mobile phonegap app

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova, voice-recognition, speech-to-text

The app in question is a phonegap app built using jquery mobile, javascript. 
It is meant for both Android and IOS.

I want to have a voice search(voice to text API/plugin) that can work on both the platforms.

Is there any such API/plugin available? If so then can it be used from within the javascript code?
i.e : is it necessary to write native code in Java/Objective C in Eclipse/Xcode for Android/IOS respectively or can i simply call it from my html page.

I found CMUSphinx but I'm not sure how to use it from within the html pages that constitute the jquery mobile app.

Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 2):

The project pocketsphinx.js (http://syl22-00.github.io/pocketsphinx.js/) may help you. It consists on a port of pocketsphinx to javascript by using emscripten.

Pro: no network connection needed, no platform dependance

Cons: heavy (naturally you need to embed models), young, and seems to need some fixes

But for little needs on phonegap, it can be used.

Good luck